# File_get_contents Returning Empty string in Localhost

Tags: php, macos, localhost, file-get-contents

Hi Below code works fine in my hosting, but not in my localhost.

```
<?php 
$hi = file_get_contents("https://ojooo.com");
echo $hi;
?>
```

But the strange thing is below code works in my Localhost.

```
<?php 
$hi = file_get_contents("https://yahoo.com");
echo $hi;
?>
```

I am really confused why the code is working in my hosting but not in my localhost.Some one please guide me what is wrong.thanks.

Comment: I am having this issue even when I use CURL to access a localhost page.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Apache Module **ssl_module**

if you are using wamp 
Click on wamp icon > apache > apache module Then Select ssl_module

Comment: yea i did it ! still blank file

Comment: I dont use Wamp.i use php directly using MAC

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your PHP Settings File (PHP.ini or conf)

The setting you are looking for is probably [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

If you want to grab the contents without changing the php settings file you can either use fsockopen or use PHP with cURL enabled.

Comment: yea its correct...but how come file_get_contents of yahoo.com working for me.. but not ojooo.com

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem described above you need to set allow_url_fopen to On  in php.ini configuration file.

This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files.

For more description about configuration parameter please refer the documentation mentioned in below url.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: In your localhost check the value of configuration parameter "allow_url_fopen" using phpinfo() function .It might be enabled on your hosting environment but might be set to off into your local environment

Comment: yea its ON,, i mean file_get_contents of yahoo.com working for me in localhost only